# In Smalltalk, how do you invoke accessor methods in Class B from within Class A on an instance of class B?

Tags: class, smalltalk, pharo

For example, in class B I have `#setValue` and `#getValue`, but I can't use these in Class A. How do I accomplish this?

edit:

what I thought would work would be `ClassBInstance setValue:1.` or even `ClassB ClassBInstance setValue:1.` but neither do.

Comment: Could you post some example code of what you're trying to accomplish? It sounds to me like you're mixing up classes and instances of classes.

Comment: You *do* use `ClassBInstance setValue:1`, assuming `ClassBInstance` is an instance of class B. How isn't it working?

Comment: As Max said, without example code, it is very difficult to help you. For example, how did you set `ClassBInstance`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an instance variable in class A say 
    `instanceVariableNames: 'binstance'`

in class A create the `initialize` method (instance side i.e. not the class side) and ensure the following code snippet is there
    `super initialize.
    ...
    bInstance := ClassB new.`

now anywhere (i.e. in any method) in ClassA use
   `bInstance setValue: 'whatever'`
or
   `myVar := bInstance getValue`

BTW in Smalltalk conventionally set and get is not used ... its simply
   setValue is `value:` 
   getValue is `value`
note difference of the `:`

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
Object subclass: #Foo  
    instanceVariableNames: ''  
    classVariableNames: 'e'  
    category: 'Example'
```

save this using ctrl+s

now generate accessors by write clicking then `Refactoring->Class Var   Refactoring->Accessors` then a box appear accept it.
Go to class side. Modify e method as

```
Foo class>>e  
    e  isNil ifTrue: [ self e: 5] .  
    ^e.
```

accept it.
Now again define a new class(remember to uncheck class side and go to   instance side).

```
Object subclass: #Faa  
    instanceVariableNames: 'a'  
    classVariableNames: ''  
    category: 'Example'
```

save this.
Now again generate accessors by right click on class `Faa` then
`Refactoring -> Class Refactoring -> Generate Accessors` then a box appear   accept it.

Now go to Playground or Workspace run these commands

```
x := Faa new.   "right click on this and select doit"  
x a.            "right click on this and select print it"  
x a: Foo e.     "right click on this and select doit"  
x a.            "right click on this and select print it"
```

you observe the difference in values of a variable.